# Reactjs FileUpload: setState throws 'insecure operation' error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to upload a file using `input[type="file"]`, and then I store the file object in my state variable, which holds an object. If I update my state, it throws error `insecure operation`.

```
        let {inventory} = this.state;
        if(!Array.isArray(inventory['photos'])){
            inventory['photos'] = [];
        }
        inventory['photos'][3 - e.target.id] = e.target.files[0];
        console.log(inventory);
        this.setState({inventory});
        console.log(this.state.inventory);
```

As I can check in my console, `console.log(inventory)` gets executed, and it throws the error in the next line.

What could be the reason for this?

I went through this GitHub issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7553 but even they don't have a clue about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons, when this warning occurs, is when you tried to set the value to the input field of type file.

if you are doing something like:

```
<input type="file" value={this.state.inventory} />
```

try to avoid setting the value to input type file.

Comment: Yes. That was it. I actually knew it, but I had two input fields that were dependent on the same state. One was dependent before the file was uploaded, and other after the state is updated, and I didn't remove the value attribute from the second attribute.

I'll mark this as correct, in case someone stumbles on to it. thanks